# How to remove one of two consecutive duplicate strings in list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list that has duplicated `'STRING'` elements and looks like this:

```
a = ['32', '55', '74', '58', 'STRING', 'STRING','STRING', 'STRING','56', '53', '51', '59', '49', '45', '45', '43', '62', '57', '53', '52', '49', '50', '47', '63', 'STRING', 'STRING', '90', '84', '82', '85', '86', 'STRING', 'STRING', '78', '88', '81', '88', '88', '73', '88', '81', '92', '129', '115', '105', '94', '91', '85', '79', '74', '69', '55', 'STRING', 'STRING', '86', '89', '88', '66', '70', 'STRING', 'STRING', '75', '73', '86', '75', '65', '57', '69', '59', '55']
```

One of every two consecuitive `'STRING'` elements has to be in its place. I need to *remove every second of the consecutive `STRING`elements*. And the list should look like this:

```
a = ['32', '55', '74', '58', 'STRING', 'STRING','56', '53', '51', '59', '49', '45', '45', '43', '62', '57', '53', '52', '49', '50', '47', '63', 'STRING', '90', '84', '82', '85', '86', 'STRING', '78', '88', '81', '88', '88', '73', '88', '81', '92', '129', '115', '105', '94', '91', '85', '79', '74', '69', '55', 'STRING', '86', '89', '88', '66', '70', 'STRING', '75', '73', '86', '75', '65', '57', '69', '59', '55']
```

This is what I tried:

```
    for i in reversed(range(len(a)-1)):       
        if (list1[i] == list1[i-1]) & (list1[i] == 'STRING'):            
            list1.remove(list1[i-1])
```

but it doesn't work. When it's not reversed I get the `IndexError`.

Comment: `list2 = ' '.join(list1).replace("STRING STRING", "STRING").split(" ")` ?

Comment: The `'45'` duplicate must remain as it is?

Comment: yes, the target is "STRING" only, all the rest elements must stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the simplest or cleanest solution, but this works:

```
a = ['32', '55', '74', '58', 'STRING', 'STRING','STRING', 'STRING','56', '53', '51', '59', '49', '45', '45', '43', '62', '57', '53', '52', '49', '50', '47', '63', 'STRING', 'STRING', '90', '84', '82', '85', '86', 'STRING', 'STRING', '78', '88', '81', '88', '88', '73', '88', '81', '92', '129', '115', '105', '94', '91', '85', '79', '74', '69', '55', 'STRING', 'STRING', '86', '89', '88', '66', '70', 'STRING', 'STRING', '75', '73', '86', '75', '65', '57', '69', '59', '55']

prev = a[0]
for el in a:
    if prev == el and el == 'STRING':
        a.remove(el)
        prev = None
    else:
        prev = el
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    if i > 0:
        if val == 'STRING' and a[i - 1] == 'STRING':
            del a[i]
```

This will remove the second STRING value that folloeing a STRING value.
Output

```
['32', '55', '74', '58', 'STRING', 'STRING','56', '53', '51', '59', '49', '45', '45', '43', '62', '57', '53', '52', '49', '50', '47', '63', 'STRING', '90', '84', '82', '85', '86', 'STRING', '78', '88', '81', '88', '88', '73', '88', '81', '92', '129', '115', '105', '94', '91', '85', '79', '74', '69', '55', 'STRING', '86', '89', '88', '66', '70', 'STRING', '75', '73', '86', '75', '65', '57', '69', '59', '55']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost good, just make `range` count backwards:

```
for i in range(len(list1)-2,-1,-1):       
    if (list1[i] == list1[i+1]) and (list1[i] == 'STRING'):            
        list1.remove(list1[i])
```

Why you got problem when removing items with your code when removed `reversed` is because the list got shorter while you were iterating over it and thus removed wrong items.

For example if your list was:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

when you remove something on `i`(which for example equals 2) then your list will be:

```
a = [1,2,4]
```

now look what is on the `i=2+1` position. Yes, it is out of range!

So, for the future, if you do a mass deletion in a list according to some condition, then do it always starting with the last item and going backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (complex) list comprehension that uses [[Python 3.Docs]: itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Note that it's generic, but also highly customizable. For example, if you also want to eliminate duplicates (apply the same logic to):

- Others (selectively: *e.g.* *'45'*): add them in the list at the end
- All: eliminate the *if* clause at the end

> ```py
> >>> import itertools as it
> >>>
> >>> initial = ['32', '55', '74', '58', 'STRING', 'STRING','STRING', 'STRING','56', '53', '51', '59', '49', '45', '45', '43', '62', '57', '53', '52', '49', '50', '47', '63', 'STRING', 'STRING', '90', '84', '82', '85', '86', 'STRING', 'STRING', '78', '88', '81', '88', '88', '73', '88', '81', '92', '129', '115', '105', '94', '91', '85', '79', '74', '69', '55', 'STRING', 'STRING', '86', '89', '88', '66', '70', 'STRING', 'STRING', '75', '73', '86', '75', '65', '57', '69', '59', '55']  # Initial
> >>>
> >>> ref = ['32', '55', '74', '58', 'STRING', 'STRING','56', '53', '51', '59', '49', '45', '45', '43', '62', '57', '53', '52', '49', '50', '47', '63', 'STRING', '90', '84', '82', '85', '86', 'STRING', '78', '88', '81', '88', '88', '73', '88', '81', '92', '129', '115', '105', '94', '91', '85', '79', '74', '69', '55', 'STRING', '86', '89', '88', '66', '70', 'STRING', '75', '73', '86', '75', '65', '57', '69', '59', '55']  # Desired
> >>>
> >>> final = [k1 for k1, gl1 in ((k0, len(list(g0))) for k0, g0 in it.groupby(initial)) for factor in range(max(gl1 // 2, 1) if k1 in ["STRING"] else gl1)]
> >>>
> >>> print(final)
> ['32', '55', '74', '58', 'STRING', 'STRING', '56', '53', '51', '59', '49', '45', '45', '43', '62', '57', '53', '52', '49', '50', '47', '63', 'STRING', '90', '84', '82', '85', '86', 'STRING', '78', '88', '81', '88', '88', '73', '88', '81', '92', '129', '115', '105', '94', '91', '85', '79', '74', '69', '55', 'STRING', '86', '89', '88', '66', '70', 'STRING', '75', '73', '86', '75', '65', '57', '69', '59', '55']
> >>>
> >>> final == ref
> True
> ```

**Note**: Modifying a sequence while iterating over it is not recommended, and doing so might yield unexpected results (for example for an initial list like `["STRING"]`). The fact that it works in this particular case, might be purely coincidental.